# initializing view holder for array list row widgets - is my approach wrong?

Tags: android

I'm adding view holder to the row of `ListView` to store widgets. Here is how I do it:

```
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (row == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.articles_list_row, parent, false);
        row.setTag(R.id.articles_list_row_widgets_holder, new TextListRowHolder(row));
    }
```

I'm also reading a book where an author initializes it like this:

```
ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
if (holder==null) {
    holder=new ViewHolder(row);
    row.setTag(holder);
}
```

Here is the quote from the book:

> If the call to getTag() on the row returns null, we know we need to
>   create a new ViewHolder, which we then attach to the row via setTag()
>   for later reuse.

Is my approach wrong? I assume that if row is null then there is no holder attached, and if the row is already created than the holder is already attached.

Answer (score 1):

no_coding_knowledge is right, you need the key to get the holder back from the tag, so `row.getTag(R.id.articles_list_row_widgets_holder);` should be the solution to your answer.

Furthermore i would recommend to get rid of the key at all, because i'm pretty sure you won't need it.
So just use `row.setTag(holder)` and `holder = row.getTag()` to set/get the holder.

In case you want to stay with your key `R.id.articles_list_row_widgets_holder`, here is some sample code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextListRowHolder holder = null;
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (row == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.articles_list_row, parent, false);
        holder = new TextListRowHolder(row);
        row.setTag(R.id.articles_list_row_widgets_holder, holder);
    } else
        holder = (TextListRowHolder)row.getTag(R.id.articles_list_row_widgets_holder);

    // do something with the holder, like holder.bind(getItem(position))...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using setTag using a specific key. So if you want to get that you must use the getTag(int key) method to get it.